# Access Query to Merge Fields form Related Table

Tags: sql, merge

So, let's say that I have table `Product`:

```
ProdID | ProdDesc
-----------------
     1 | Widget
     2 | Snikt Spring
     3 | Water Bearing
```

and table `ProdFeature`

```
ProdID | DocID | ProdSafe | ProdShiny
-------------------------------------
     1 |    34 | Y        | Null
     1 |    17 | Null     | Y
     2 |    54 | Y        | Null
     3 |     2 | Null     | Y
```

How would I get a result like:

```
ProdID | ProdSafe | SafetyDocID | ProdShiny | ShinyDocID
--------------------------------------------------------
     1 | Y        |          34 | Y         |         17
```

Any help is appreciated. ~R

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```
SELECT p.ProdID,
       pf1.ProdSafe,
       pf1.DocID SafetyDocID,
       pf2.ProdShiny,
       pf2.DocID ShinyDocID
  FROM Product p
           left outer join ProdFeature pf1
               on p.ProdID = pf1.ProdID and pf1.ProdSafe is not null
           left outer join ProdFeature pf2
               on p.ProdID = pf2.ProdID and pf2.ProdShiny is not null
```

[Here is a Demo.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc6a8/5)

Another version, which is **less performant**:

```
SELECT p.ProdID,
       (select ProdSafe
          from ProdFeature
         where ProdID = p.ProdID
               and ProdSafe is not null) ProdSafe,
       (select DocID
          from ProdFeature
         where ProdID = p.ProdID
               and ProdSafe is not null) SafetyDocID,
       (select ProdShiny
          from ProdFeature
         where ProdID = p.ProdID
               and ProdShiny is not null) ProdShiny,
       (select DocID
          from ProdFeature
         where ProdID = p.ProdID
               and ProdShiny is not null) ShinyDocID
  FROM Product p
```

[Here is a Demo.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc6a8/3)